# SQL Functions Overflow

Tags: function, google-analytics, where-clause

I'm having trouble figuring out which SQL function allows me to locate a specific table in a query. I can't figure out if it's the WHERE or the FROM clause.

I have trying to use both, but for someone reason I have been getting an error on SQL.